# React props from child to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I started practicing React.
I'm trying to create a simple app that would count how many kg of plastic do we use, according on how many bottles of water we use every day.
Using this info, I want to show what could be produced out of recycled plastic that we use per year.

So I have a component Calculator:

```js
class Calculator extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        resultNumber: null,
        resultKg: null
      }
    }


    count = (e) => {

      let val = e.target.value;
      let resultNumber = val * 52;
      let resultKg = Math.round(resultNumber * 0.04);
      this.setState({
        resultNumber: resultNumber,
        resultKg: resultKg
      })
    }

    render() {
      return ( <div >
        <Menu / >
        <div className = "component" >

        <h1 > I use < input type = "text" className = "input-data" onChange = {this.count}/>  bottles per week</h1 >

          <div className = "resultInfo" > {this.state.resultNumber != null ?
            <Info resultNumber = {this.state.resultNumber}
            resultKg = { this.state.resultKg } />  :null} < /div> 
</div>

          </div>
        )
      }

    }
```

I have a component that shows the result:

```js
const Info = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
        <div className="info">
        <div><p>{props.resultNumber} bottles per year</p>
        <img src={bottle1} />
        </div>

        <div><p>{props.resultKg} kg of plastic per year</p>
        <img src={trash} />
        </div>
       
         </div>
         <p><a href="/recycle">What could be produced out of {props.resultKg} kg of plastic?</a></p>
         </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the {props.resultKg} in another component that renders what could be produced:

```js
const Recycle = (props) => {
   return({props.resultKg})
    }
```

The last component, of course, returns "undefined".

I tried to learn Redux but it became overwhelming and I got even more confused. Could you help me to understand how I can get state from Calculator in my Recycle component?

Comment: what is relationship in Calculator and Recycle component

Comment: Look into unidirectional data flow in React... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unidirectional-data-flow/ And lifting up state: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz, well, basically now there is no relationship between these two components.

Comment: @SakoBu, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to learn Redux to make it. :)